# Correct Terminology for Windows Login Formats

Tags: windows, login

What's the correct terminology for referring to the different forms of user identfiers that I come across in a Windows network?
To be specific, I have to use these 3 for different systems at my place of employment, Given my name is Fred Flintone and I work at FooCorp, I have to use these various forms depending on the system:

flinstonef

foocorpdomain\flintstonef

fred.flinstone@foocorp.com

What is the correct term to refer to each of these?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Correct terms for each of these -

Flinstonef - User account name or logon name

Oocorpdomain\flintstonef - Down-Level Logon Name

fred.flinstone@foocorp.com - User Principal Name

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was just what I needed, as it gave me the correct terms I needed to do more research, e.g.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/user-name-formats?redirectedfrom=MSDN, and
https://superuser.com/questions/631963/what-are-the-specific-names-for-the-various-username-formats-in-windows

Comment: "User account name" is also called SamAccountName.